# How to open class wizard in mfc (VS 2003.Net) via menu?

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2003, classwizard

I have some old VS 2003 in my virtual box to just learning and practice C++ and relative things. So, I can't use "Ctrl+W" to open "Class Wizard". Does anybody know how to get it via menu?
Thanks in advance

Comment: So, I found this:
https://www.fabulatech.com/virtual-serial-port-control-sdk/integration-ax-vs6-vc.html

Comment: VS 2003 is not an environment to learn and practice C++. Its compiler is riddled with non-standard behavior and lacks everything we refer to as *"modern C++"* (that is, C++11 and later). MFC is even a decade older than this ancient compiler. This is a combination that will teach you a lot of things you will eventually have to unlearn again.